# Using WP Navigation-Bar Elsewhere

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, drop-down-menu, phpbb

I have a wordpress site and a phpbb3 site, I want to use the wordpress navigation(menu) in the phpbb3 site also.

Since the Menus will be changing in constantly (I use Wp-Menus) I do not just want to copy and paste the HTML code.

Please Help!

Comment: Is WP-Menus a plugin and if you want help that pertains specifically to it, could you post a link?

Comment: Wordpress - [GadgetArena](http://gadgetarena.in) 
Phpbb3    - [Forum | GadgetArena](http://forum.gadgetarena.in)

Comment: U see there is no nav-bar in [Forum](http://gadgetarena.in)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to copy the HTML/CSS and then fetch menu items from the WP database. Involving Wordpress would only make this more advanced and add more overhead.